# Unable to do code with list in python

Tags: python, list

I am new to python and learning from CodeAcademy.com; I have a problem:

> Change **list_function** so that:
>
> 1. Add 3 to the item at index one of the list.
> 2. **Store the result back into index one.**
> 3. **Return the list.**

Here is my code:

```
def list_function(x):
    return x

n = [3, 5, 7]
n.insert(1,3)
print list_function(n)
```

I get only the error, what should i do?

My problem is to understand the number 2 and 3 option.

Comment: I don't see any *errors* here.

Comment: If you're using python 3 I think you need to use print with function syntax i.e print(list_function(n))

Comment: @JohnGreenall: lets confuse the user some more.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - trying to be helpful! when I tried following a dive into python tutorial years ago I was using python 3 and got stuck for half an hour wondering why i couldn't get "hello world" to work!

Comment: I have done to solve it.....  
`def list_function(x):
    x[1] += 3
    return x

n = [3, 5, 7]
print list_function(n)`

Comment: @JohnGreenall: sure, but reserve that advice for when they actually show that there was a problem with printing..

Comment: @MarounMaroun: you may want to read the instructions more carefully.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I said *errors* - "I get only the error"

Comment: @MarounMaroun: ah, yes, misunderstood what you meant. You may want to be explicit about *please post the error you got here* next time. CodeAcademy gives the student a message that their solution is wrong, I believe, but there was no *Python exception* here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I agree, thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing *adding* with *inserting*, point 1:

> 1. Add 3 to the item at index one of the list.

You interpreted this as insertion:

```
n.insert(1,3)
```

but really they meant the *arithmetic operation*:

```
n[1] + 3
```

This *adds 3* (with `+`) tot the *item at index one* (`[1]`) of the list (`n`).

You then insert that back into the list at the same index:

```
n[1] = n[1] + 3
```

All this should be done inside your function:

```
def list_function(some_list):
    some_list[1] = some_list[1] + 3  # step 1 and 2
    return some_list                 # step 3
```

Comment: Spot on; the question was triggered by the overloaded meaning of `add`. For the record, if you are willing to combine step 1 and 2 into a single statement you might consider using `some_list[1] += 3` (though this might be considered 'less explicit' about what's going on).